# My node.js server script is serving the index.html fine, but not the CSS or other static files

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to write a Node.js project from a tutorial, but the server.js file does not seem to be working properly:

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var mime = require('mime');
var cache = {};

function send404(response) {
response.writeHead(404, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
response.write('Error 404: not found');
response.end();
}

function sendFile(response, filePath, fileContents) {
response.writeHead(
200,
{"content-type": mime.lookup(path.basename(filePath))}
);
response.end(fileContents);
}

function serveStatic(response, cache, absPath) {
if (cache[absPath]) {
sendFile(response, absPath, cache[absPath]);
} else {
fs.exists(absPath, function(exists) {
if (exists) {
fs.readFile(absPath, function(err, data) {
if (err) {
send404(response);
} else {
cache[absPath] = data;

sendFile(response, absPath, data);
}
});
} else {
send404(response);

}
});
}
}

var server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
var filePath = false;

if(request.url == '/') {
filePath = 'public/index.html';
} else {
filePath = '/public/' + request.url;
}
var absPath = './' + filePath;
serveStatic(response, cache, absPath);
});

server.listen(26353, function() {
console.log("Listening...");
});
```

When I go to my URL the index.html content is displayed, but none of the stylesheets or attached files from the index.html are displayed, I get:

```
 GET http://myURL.com/stylesheet/style.css 404 (NOT FOUND)
```

Here is my index.html:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Chat</title>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheet/style.css'></link>
</head>

<body>
<div id='content'>
<div id='room'></div>
<div id='room-list'></div>
<div id='messages'></div>

<form id='send-form'>
<input id='send-message' />
<input id='send-button' type='submit' value='Send' />

<div id='help'>
Chat commands:
<ul>
<li>.....</li>
</ul>
</div>
</form>
</div>

<script src='/socket.io/socket.io.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script src='/javascript/chat.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script src='/javascript/chat_ui.js' type='text/javascript'></script>

</body>
</html>
```

I'm not sure what is wrong.

My project directory has the server.js, the node-modules and the public folder, the public folder has a stylesheet directory and javascript folder where the files are.

My web host has is set up so that http://myURL.com/node/ is where port 26353 is bound to (don't know if that's the right word). So if I go to http://myURL.com/node I see the index.html file but none of the stylesheets or javascript works.

Comment: Have you looked at expressjs? http://expressjs.com/guide.html Express has built in functionality for serving static files.

Comment: This line filePath = '/public/' + request.url should be filePath = '/public' + request.url (notice that I removed the trailing slash from public). You can also add a bunch of "console.log('something')" to see what part of your program is executing and validate that is has the values that you expect.

Comment: By the way, here is a full example of web server in Node.js https://gist.github.com/hectorcorrea/2573391

Answer (score 1):

Sending file is not so trivial in node.js. There is a code from my framework

```
core.sendFile = function(filename, context)
{
    if (fs.exists(filename, function (exists)
    {
        if (exists) fs.stat(filename, function (err, stats)
        {
            if (err) core.catch_err(err);
            else if (stats && !stats.isDirectory())
            {
                var filestream = new fs.ReadStream(filename);
                var mimme = mime.lookup(filename);
                context.response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': mimme });
                filestream.pipe(context.response);
                filestream.on("error", function (err) { context.response.statusCode = "500"; context.response.end("Server error"); core.log("Server error while sending " + filename, "err"); });
                context.response.on("close", function () { filestream.destroy(); });
                core.logger.log("Sending file " + filename);
            }
        });
        else core.not_found(context);
    }));
}
```

The idea is to read and write file as a stream, and to process some errors and closing of streams. "Core" is just a library object.

Answer (score 0):

remove the first / from your url, so it should be `stylesheet/style.css` instead of `/stylesheet/style.css`